# OptionMenu on multiple windows with single mainloop

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import Tkinter as tk
import guiOpMenu2

class Omenu(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = tk.Tk()
        self.app.title('test1')
        self.OpMenu()
        self.btn()

    def OpMenu(self):
        self.op = tk.StringVar()
        self.opt =['1', '2']
        self.men = tk.OptionMenu(self.app, self.op, *self.opt)
        self.men.pack()

    def btn(self):
        self.btn_btn = tk.Button(self.app, text='newGui', command=self.test)
        self.btn_btn.pack()

    def test(self):
        win = guiOpMenu2.Omenu2()

win = Omenu()
win.app.mainloop()

import Tkinter as tk
class Omenu2(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = tk.Tk()
        self.app.title('test1')
        self.OpMenu2()

    def OpMenu2(self):
        self.op2 = tk.StringVar()
        self.opt2 =['2', '3']
        self.men2 = tk.OptionMenu(self.app, self.op2, *self.opt2, command=self.test)
        self.men2.pack()

    def test(self, num):
       print self.op2.get()
       print num
```

Clicking on the button newGui displays the new window, but the selected value does not show up on the second optionmenu widget. When I do print self.op2.get() or print num it does print the selected value though. What can be done to make the second optionmenu behave properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue occurs because in `Omenu2` class, you are creating a new `Tk()` app.

Also, unless the `.mainloop()` is called for the application owning a component, its widgets would not get updated.

Also, I don't think you really need a new `Tk()` app itself. If you want the new option menu to come in a new window, you should use [`tk.Toplevel()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) .

Example -

The guiOpmenu2.py -

```
import Tkinter as tk
class Omenu2(object):

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
        self.master = tk.Toplevel(app)
        self.master.title('test1')
        self.OpMenu2()

    def OpMenu2(self):
        self.op2 = tk.StringVar()
        self.opt2 =['2', '3']
        self.men2 = tk.OptionMenu(self.master, self.op2, *self.opt2, command=self.test)
        self.men2.pack()

    def test(self, num):
       print self.op2.get()
       print num
```

Your main script -

```
import Tkinter as tk
import guiOpMenu2

class Omenu(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = tk.Tk()
        self.app.title('test1')
        self.OpMenu()
        self.btn()

    def OpMenu(self):
        self.op = tk.StringVar()
        self.opt =['1', '2']
        self.men = tk.OptionMenu(self.app, self.op, *self.opt)
        self.men.pack()

    def btn(self):
        self.btn_btn = tk.Button(self.app, text='newGui', command=self.test)
        self.btn_btn.pack()

    def test(self):
        win = guiOpMenu2.Omenu2(self.app)

win = Omenu()
win.app.mainloop()
```